# The intersection of two sets of natural numbers defined via primes is infinite

Tags: prime-numbers, congruences

Any given prime $P \in \mathbb P$ is either of the form $$ P \equiv -1 \mod 6$$ or $$ P \equiv 1 \mod 6.$$ In other words, every prime greater than 3 can be expressed in the form $$P = 5+6n \vee 7 + 6n $$ Proof is easy. Any prime must be

$$\begin{cases} P \equiv 1 \mod 2 \\
P \equiv 1 \vee -1 \mod 3
\end{cases}$$

if the latter is $1$, we get $2 \ | \ (P-1) \wedge 3 \ | \ (P-1),$ so $6 \ | \ (P-1)$ and if it is $-1$, we get $2 \ | \ (P+1) \wedge 3 \ | \ (P+1),$ so $6 \ | \ (P+1)$.

Now, we also know that there are infinitely many primes of both forms, as proven somewhere on this site.

This means that there is infinite number of such numbers $n \in \mathbb N$ that $$5+6 n \in P$$ and infite number of such $k \in \mathbb N$ that $$7+6 k \in P.$$ This also means that we have $\forall P>3 \in \mathbb P,$ some kind of infinite set $S_P$ such that $$P + 6 s \in \mathbb P, \forall s\in S_P $$ because, say, we assume $P = 5+ 6 m$ then $$(5 + 6m) + 6s = 5+(m+s)6$$ and here we use the first argument, just shifted forwards by $m$.

Now, denote the set of such $k$ for some $P$ that $P + 6k \in \mathbb P$ by $K_P$.

If we keep all $P \equiv 5 \mod 6$, I would suggest that the intersection $K_{P_1}\cap K_{P_2}$ of two such sets is also infinitely large. Is it?

So if we $P_1 = 5 + 6s$ and $P_2 = 5 + 6 t$, we get two sets $\{s+1,s+2,s+3\cdots\}$ and $\{m+1,m+2,m+3\cdots\}.$ Is it possible that the running terms never coincide with respect to primality of the numbers in question? Could this be proven impossible with, for example, using pigeonhole principle? Or something to do with filters? I am sure that if the definitions were modified a bit, one could acquire filter bases.

Comment: It sounds likely that if we could answer such questions, the methods could also be used to attack the famed _Twin Prime Conjecture_ (which in your notation asks whether $K_5\cap K_7$ is infinite).

Comment: Your argument that "there are infinitely many numbers $s$ ..." doesn't seem to hold water. In fact it is easy to see that _no_ such $s$ can exist -- it can't work for any $P$ that's a prime factor of $6s$ itself, for example.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am aware of the connection to twin primes. So I avoided asking about that by asking only about primes with same congruence with 6. Also, if P is a prime factor of s makes no sense to me as s is supposed to be a variable. It is true that there is infinitely many s such that for some P the sum is not a prime, but also infinitely many for which it is. Or what did you mean? And of course P is greater than 3.

Comment: x @Valtteri: Your claim is that there exist infinitely many $s$ with the property that for every prime $P$ it holds that $P+6s$ is also prime. That is simply false -- you cannot even show ONE $s$ with that property.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Do you agree that there is infinitely many k such that 5 + 6k is a prime? If you do, consider a prime which is of the form 5+6m. Then 5+6m + 6s = 5+6(s+m). There is infinitely many primes of the form 5+6k, pick one such k>m = K, so select s so that K=m+s. m+s is linear, so there is such an s.

Comment: x @Valtteri: Please show me just one concrete $s$ that you claim has the property you speak of.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, of course I didn't say that you have some s for which 6s+P is always a prime for every P. I meant that for every prime there is a different set of s

Comment: x @Valtteri: What you say is, quoted exactly: "we have infinitely many numbers $s$ such that $\forall P\in \mathbb P$, $P+6s\in \mathbb P$". That is **not true**.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you are right. With that wording it is not true. Sorry. I will try to come up with more correct one.